# How do I make my d3 pie chart occupy as much width as possible?

Tags: d3.js, svg, pie-chart

I'm using d3 v4.  I want to create a pie chart (with labels) and I would like it to occupy as much space (width) as it can (the height can vary depending on how much it needs).  So I crated my SVG element

```
<svg width="700" height="400">
    <g id="labels" />
</svg>
```

and the JS to draw my pie chart

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = 1000,
    height = +200,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

But it seems like no matter what value I put in for "width" in the JS, it just seems to move my chart over to the right and there is a giant gap of unused space to its left:

https://jsfiddle.net/vp9zsL2a/1/

Is there a way I can make my pie chart (with its labels) take up as much horizontal space as is available?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you take minimum of width and height for radius `radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2` so no matter how much you increase the width pie chart will never be more than 200px in radius. Try increasing the height too and it will get bigger.